# "last week" versus "over last week"

Tags: usage

> A number of reactivations were performed **over last week**.
>
> A number of reactivations were performed **last week**.

What is the difference when putting "over" before "last week"?

Comment: The first example needs *the*: "A number of reactivations were performed **over the last week**."

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences between the sentences.

> A number of reactivations were performed over *the* last week. [As snailplane suggests in the comment, a native speaker would use *the*.]

This sentence means that the reactivations being discussed occurred during the last *seven days* and probably at several different points (at least two) .

> A number of reactivations were performed last week.

This sentence means that the reactivations occurred at some time during the last *calendar week* (which may or may not be the last seven days).  In US usage, the phrase *last week*, (without *the*) almost always means last calendar week. There is no suggestion about whether they all occurred at the same time or were spaced out in time.

The sentences differ in the exact period of time being discussed and the spacing of the events. There are many circumstances when either could be used, but other circumstances when only one or the other would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'over' refers to that period of time (in this case, the last week). It's used [to express duration.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/over?q=over). We say *You'll get an experience over the period of time.*, don't we?

On the other hand, if you just leave 'last week', it simply means it happened somewhere in last week.