# During the past week

Tags: time-reference

Please look at the following and tell me what the difference between them is

1. During the past week, Chris has answered the phone.
2. During the past week, Chris answered the phone.

When I say "during the past week' does it mean the week still continues? I mean does it extend up to the present time of speaking? Or has it ended?

When do I use Present perfect and simple past with during?

Also

What is the difference between

3. In the past week, ***Chris has answered the phone*.**
4. In the past week, ***Chris answered the phone***.

Also is there any difference ***between past week and last week?***

Comment: This is really two questions, the second of which is answered [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/18220/18196).

Comment: It's the verb tense that tells you if 'the past week' has ended. With the simple past, it has. With the present perfect, almost certainly not.

Comment: Alan sir, I am confused now. On the one hand we use ' during the past week' so that means irrespective of the tense the week continues till present and there can be no question of it ending, as 'during the past week means it is continuing'. This is my understanding of it.  When you say the week has not ended what do you mean by that? Does it mean we are in the third or fourth day of the week? And when you say the week has ended does it mean we are in the seventh day of the week? This is all confusing. Please clear the doubt sir. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present perfect can generally, with few exceptions, only be used with an adverbial of time that **includes** the moment of speaking.

Meanwhile, the simple past (or: past simple) cannot include an adverbial of time that includes the present. On this point, see [When a sentence includes a word like 'today' that indicates present time, can a past form of verb be used?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74351/when-a-sentence-includes-a-word-like-today-that-indicates-present-time-can-a)

In

> During the past week, Chris has answered the phone.

the time period  *the past week* is not considered to be over  when the speaker says this sentence.

In

> During the past week, Chris answered the phone.

the time period *the past week* is considered to be all in the past, i.e.,  *not including* the present moment.

Answer (score 0):

"During the past week" refers to the 7 or so days leading up to today. It may or may not have ended. "Last week" refers to the period from Sunday that ended with the most recent Saturday (or depending on context it may refer to Monday to Friday). Last week has ended.

Comment: Readin I didn't understand what you mean by 'the week may or may not have ended'. During the past week as you say means it extends upto the present, so the week continues and cannot end. So please tell me the example of when the week may have ended.