# The past two weeks with present perfect or past simple

Tags: difference, verbs, present-perfect, past-simple

What is the difference between,

> "I **have been spending** the last 2 weeks trying to convince him I really care about him and yesterday you ruined everything."

vs.

> "I **spent** the last 2 weeks trying to convince him I really care about him and yesterday you ruined everything."

Comment: In my opinion, the progressive prefect is usually used to imply a repetition of doing something, so I myself as a learner, however, prefer the simple form.

Comment: The first option you give, "I have been spending", is actually the progressive perfect, as Cardinal points out.  I think the present perfect, "I have spent", would actually be the best option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [During the past week](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89262/during-the-past-week)

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically right. One could argue that the present perfect puts more emphasis (just by making the phrase longer) on the amount of time. More important in a grammatical sense, however, is that present perfect implies that the task is ongoing. "Spent" puts the action completely in the past. "Have been spending" suggests that it is not finished.